# vectorized way to add a calculated row to a multindex's subindex

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I cannot get my head around how to use groupby to solve the following example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'kitchen': ['galley', 'house', 'restaurant', 'caterer'] * 3,
        'products': ['chocolate', 'tart', 'pie', ] * 4,
        'menu_a': [pd.np.random.randint(100000, 999999) for _ in range(12)],
        'menu_b': [pd.np.random.randint(100000, 999999) for _ in range(12)],
        'menu_c': [pd.np.random.randint(100000, 999999) for _ in range(12)]
    }
).set_index(['kitchen', 'products']).sort_index()
```

df

What I want to do is replace the "pie" and "tart" rows of each kitchen with the sum of pie+tart for each kitchen.

[image]

So for example, in the `galley` `kitchen`, the new row under `products` would be `pastries` and the value under `menu_a` would be `333163+612456 = 945619`   for each of the `kitchen` x `product` x `menu`s.

I've tried many versions `stack()` `unstack()` and `groupby()` mixed togther but cannot quite get the result. The alternative is to do this iteratively/`apply()`'d outside, which is gross, and this is a frequent problem I encounter. Would like to know how to do it right.

Comment: Do you need remove `pie` with `tart` ?

Comment: @jezrael yeah, I want to drop the two rows that i summed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select rows by second level, sum and add second level:

```
df1 = (df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, ['pie','tart']], :]
         .sum(level=0)
         .assign(products='total')
         .set_index('products', append=True))
```

Then concat to original and remove used values by list:

```
df = pd.concat([df, df1]).drop(['pie','tart'], level=1).sort_index()
print (df)
                       menu_a   menu_b   menu_c
kitchen    products                            
caterer    chocolate   907615   167480   921843
           total       749664   786464   872046
galley     chocolate   939850   382545   525525
           total      1204359   907760  1267475
house      chocolate   701797   106570   572014
           total      1215235  1058951   812935
restaurant chocolate   734501   637600   216367
           total      1846097   345020   517969
```

Comment: you always write your code snippets in the most-readable way imaginable. You are the epitome-opposite of a code golfer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One way using `rename`:

```
new_df = df.rename({'pie':'pastries', 'tart':'pastries'}).sum(level=[0, 1])
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
                       menu_a   menu_b   menu_c
kitchen    products                            
caterer    chocolate   369612   505912   988729
           pastries   1647943  1119303  1391204
galley     chocolate   128946   196457   669335
           pastries   1215293  1573815  1108319
house      chocolate   397620   167103   193412
           pastries    509144   741824   416904
restaurant chocolate   330240   306817   835125
           pastries    584582  1395824  1098987
```